# Change parabolic equation to canonical form

Tags: functions, problem-solving, plane-curves, quadratic-forms

I have equation $y = -x^2 + 2x + 7$. 
How can I change it to canonical form, which looks like $y^2 = 2px$ ?
($p$ will be parameter)

What i ve tried so far:
$$\begin{align}
y &= -x^2 + 2x + 7\\ 
y &= -(x^2 - 2x + 1) + 8\\ 
(y-8) &= -(x-1)^2 \\
(y-8)^2 &= 2*(0.5)*(x-1)^4
\end{align}
$$

But I have read somewhere its wrong, so how do I make it correct?

Or is my solution correct?

Comment: I have edited and reformatted your question. Please read the faq or see here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for questions about how to use LaTeX (MathJax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$-y=x^2-2x-7=(x-1)^2-8\implies (x-1)^2=-(y-8)$$
 which is of the form $(x-\alpha)^2=-4a(y-\beta)$

Now, if we are allowed to make the transformation of axes, we can set $x-1=Y,y-8=X$

So,$Y^2=-X=2\left(-\frac12\right)X$

Comment: well i need it strictly y^2=2px , but from your comment i can say i ve probably done my version right

Comment: @user1849353, the Right Hand Side in your method is of  $O(x^4),$ right? But we need $O(x)$

Comment: Well (x−1)^2=−(y−8) only looks like y^2=2px after you flip x and y by defining X and Y ... is it really the only way ?

Comment: @user1849353, I think so.

Comment: allrightey, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$y = -x^2 + 2x + 7 $$
$$y = -(x^2 - 2x +1)+8 $$
$$y = -(x- 1)^2+8 $$
$$(x- 1)^2=-(y-8) $$
$$(x- 1)^2=2(-\frac{1}{2})(y-8)\Rightarrow p=-\frac{1}{2},x-1=Y,y-8=X $$
$$Y^2=2pX$$